# Lost expired Indian passport and other documents

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, lost-documents

I landed in Manchester today on a brief visit. And, somewhere in the airport, I lost my **expired and cancelled** Indian passport, and a credit card, and my Indian tax ID. I called the non-emergency contact for Manchester police, and the operator told me that they don't accept any reports of lost objects anymore. I was asked to report it on https://www.reportmyloss.com/uk/. This really doesn't serve my purpose. The website looks like it is privately owned.

I would like to report it and get an acknowledgement. I need this because, a) I will need it because I need it to report it to the Indian authorities, and b) some countries ask for all travel documents, expired or otherwise, within a specific timeframe. I will need this to indicate that I don't have mine anymore.

What do I need to to do in order to make an official report? Would really appreciate any help on this. Just to make it clear, I cleared UK immigration with a valid UK visa and valid Indian passport, which is still in my possession.

Comment: The FAQ suggests the site is "police-supported" and is used by UK police departments who don't handle lost property reports, so it may well be your least bad/only option.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Yes, I did read it, but going through the sign up procedure, and a quick read over of the privacy policy made me rethink the procedure. In any event, I found the missing documents. Some kind soul found my document and handed them over to the lost and found at Manchester Airport. I managed to collect it back from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to resolve my issue without any complaints to the police. Someone found my lost documents and handed them over to the lost and found office at Manchester Airport. I contacted them to see if this had happened, and I was in luck.

Just in case, anyone reads this to see what to do in a similar situation, here is what Manchester police [advice](https://For%20UK%20passports%20or%20driving%20licences,%20report%20the%20loss%20to%20the%20Passport%20Office%20or%20DVLA.%20%20For%20foreign%20passports,%20ID%20cards%20and%20driving%20licences,%20please%20report%20the%20loss%20to%20us%20at%20a%20police%20station.%20Please%20use%20the%20finder%20below%20to%20find%20the%20station%20closest%20to%20where%20you%20lost%20the%20item.%20%20For%20bank%20cards%20or%20other%20official%20documents,%20such%20as%20birth%20certificates%20and%20bank%20statements,%20report%20the%20loss%20to%20the%20office%20that%20issued%20it.%20%20If%20the%20item%20is%20handed%20in%20to%20us%20then%20we%20will%20make%20efforts%20to%20contact%20you.).

> For UK passports or driving licences, report the loss to the Passport Office or DVLA.
>
> For foreign passports, ID cards and driving licences, please report
> the loss to us at a police station. Please use the finder below to
> find the station closest to where you lost the item.
>
> For bank cards or other official documents, such as birth certificates
> and bank statements, report the loss to the office that issued it.
>
> If the item is handed in to us then we will make efforts to contact
> you.